# How can I refresh One Form when other Form is closed VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I want to refresh Form1 when Form2 is closed,
I have searched a lot but none of those queries answered my question.

I want to detect the Form2 closing event in Form1.

Comment: There are multiple ways: one is to create a class with an new event FormOpenChanged and subscribe to it in Form1. Another way is create a Public Boolean variable that changes when Form2 is Loaded and Closed. Another one is to just change Visibility property of Form2 instead of closing, and inspecting Form2.visible from Form1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not refresh Form1 in the Closed event of Form2?

```
    Private Sub Form2_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        Form1.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have an instance of Form2, and you `AddHandler` to subscribe to its `Closed` event.

I don't know how you create your Form2. So here is a solution which should work in your case. Just replace `_myForm2 = New Form2()` with however yours is created

```
Public Class Form1

    Public ReadOnly Property MyForm2 As Form2
        Get
            Static _myForm2 As Form2
            If _myForm2 Is Nothing Then
                _myForm2 = New Form2() ' replace with how your Form2 is created
            End If
            Return _myForm2
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler MyForm2.FormClosed, AddressOf myForm2_Closed ' add event handler
        MyForm2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub myForm2_Closed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you are using a default Form2 instance, you shouldn't be. But if you must, you would use `_myForm2 = Form2`